# Detect change without having two tex files

Tags: pdftex, latexdiff

I need to detect changes between two pdf files. When I made corrections to my thesis, I worked on the same tex file. So I do not have two different tex files. Now how can I detect the changes in the two files?

Comment: https://people.cispa.io/cas.cremers/misc/pdfdiff.html

Comment: @DG', any other suggestion, please? I am not familiar with Python. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can use a utility such as pdftotext (which you may already have) and get two text versions and then diff those

Comment: but you wouldn't have to know python to run the script suggested in the first comment, just need to have python installed so you can run it.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you.  @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @gultu - `pdfdiff` is just a program. No need to know python.

Comment: If you would use a version-control system like Git you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Or even just rsnapshot or Time Machine or similar programme to make daily snapshots